# Size of a small window

Tags: swift, macos

Do windows have any limit in size?. I tried to give for instance 100px and 50px in storyboard Size Inspector. When I publish it shows much larger.

Comment: i suspect that this might be due to scaling settings in mac display options.

Comment: What is the size of its content view?

Comment: @Wileke 100px x 50px

Comment: Why the negative point? I have Google it intensely and there is no information about it. Please, tell me what I have to do to improve the question

Comment: So you set Window Content Size to 100x50 and ViewController's View Width to 100 and Height to 50 in IB? Works for me - I get a window of 100x50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many things, I could figure out the solution. In fact, there is no problem to make a window 100 x 50 px or even smaller. The problem is that I had to close the window of the simulator before run again. In my case, such a small window had no Title bar and no close button. So I had to publish with the Title bar, close it, stop the running and then I could run again with the new size and position I give to the window.

So, without closing the window in the simulator it is not possible to see the results of a new size.